# Django profile id may not not null using get_or_create, how does it relate to the db?

Tags: database, django, sqlite, profile

I followed a bit the steps on [Django User Profiles - Simple yet powerful](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile).

Not quite the same because I am in the middle of developing the idea.
From this site I used in particular, also this line:

> User.profile = property(lambda u:
>   UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

I was getting always an error message on creating the object, typically
"XX" may not be null. I solved part of the problems by playing with models
and (in my present case) sqliteman. Till I got the same
message on the id: "xxx.id may not be null".

On the net I found a description of a possible solution which involved doing a reset
of the database, which I was not that happy to do. In particular because for the
different solutions, it might have involved the reset of the application db.

But because the UserProfile model was kinda new and till now empty,
I played with it on the DB directly and made an hand made drop of the table and
ask syncdb to rebuilt it. (kinda risky thought).

Now this is the diff of the sqlite dump:

```
294,298c290,294
< CREATE TABLE "myt_userdata" (
<     "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
<     "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
<     "url" varchar(200),
<     "birthday" datetime
---
> CREATE TABLE myt_userdata (
>     "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
>     "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
>     "url" VARCHAR(200),
>     "birthday" DATETIME
```

Please note that both versions are generated by django. The ">" version was generated with a simple model definition which had indeed the connection with the user table via:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

The new "<" version has much more information and it is working.

My question:

Why Django complains about an myt_userdata.id may not be null?

The subsidiary question:

Does Django tries to relate to the underline db structure, how?
(for example the not NULL message comes from the model or from the DB?)

The additional question:

I have been a bit reluctant to the use south: Too complicated, additional modules
which I might have to care between devel and production and maybe not that easy
if I want to switch DB engine (I am using sqlite only at devel stage, I plan to move to
mysql).

Probably south might have worked in this case. Would it work? would you suggest its use
anyway?

Edited FIY:

This is my last model (the working one):

```
class UserData(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    url = models.URLField("Website", blank=True, null=True)

    birthday = models.DateTimeField('Birthday', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserData.objects.get_or_create(user=u,defaults={'birthday': '1970-01-01 00:00:00'})[0])
```

Comment: The main reason I am asking this is that I found a couple of situations where a db reset was required. I mean pretty obvious

Comment: `unique` `ForeignKey` is the `OneToOneField`

Comment: they should be "almost" equivalent except, from the docs: but the "reverse" side of the relation will directly return a single object. which is not that fully clear to me.

Comment: To be clear (if you do not read fully the given link). I had a UserData model which I moved to become a "UserProfile" (I kept the old class name). But the question is a little different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Django complains about an myt_userdata.id may not be null?

Because `id` is not a primary key and is not populated automatically though. Also, you don't provide it on model creation, so DB does not know what to do.

> Does Django tries to relate to the underline db structure, how? (for example the not NULL message comes from the model or from the DB?)

It's an error from DB, not from Django.

You can use [sql command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#sql-appname-appname) to understan what exactly is executed on syncdb. Variant above seems to be correct table definition made from correct Django model, and I have no ide how have you got a variant below. Write a correct and clear model, and you'll get correct and working table scheme after `syncdb`

Comment: Cheers, It sounds so obvious. Time to time you just need a good plain description. ;) I marked you up but before to give it as an answer I want to check again how the first table definition was created. Yours indeed seems to solve the get_or_create() problem, or I guess so ;). For the DB, I definitely didn't type it! and the model was defined to be connected to the users since the beginning. I double check how I generated it.. and by the way: thanks.

Comment: In my last comment, "since the beginning" means that only lately I moved the model to be a UserProfile models.. can it be part of the problem?

Comment: mm.. It might be an sqlite problem.. but I do not see an AUTO INCREMENT in the second definition either.. but I am not an sqlite expert. It actually sends us back to the original question: how django realtes to the db engine?

Comment: I checked. It seems I did a mistake. On opening the DB with sqliteman and most probably (read for sure) opening alter table, even hitting on the cancel button changed the database definition. It is a sqliteman problem. Or maybe a django/sqlite problem. I accept this answer with a remark: It would be nice to get the original exception from the dbengine so that I would't ask ;) I mean, who generated the exception: may not be NULL.

Comment: I'd like to reopen the problem. Before I thought I might messed up by using sqliteman.. but I get the same problem again. Now I have a defined model, a defined modelForm, and a clear view. I get the problem again. Is Django working oddly with sqlite?

Comment: Django works good with sqlite. How are you creating the table?

Comment: I let django doing the tables. But probably it is not an sqlite problem but indeed sqliteman. Which I used to change the tables.. can it be?

Comment: What are you "changing" there and why?